# java.net.socketexception: The operation timed out problem in android?

Tags: android

In my application i wrote code for connecting to the URL like below

```
InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
```

i got the error.Iam sending my logcat

```
12-17 15:06:55.065: WARN/System.err(4952): java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
12-17 15:06:55.065: WARN/System.err(4952):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocketImpl(Native Method)
12-17 15:06:55.065: WARN/System.err(4952):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(OSNetworkSystem.java:115)
12-17 15:06:55.065: WARN/System.err(4952):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:244)
12-17 15:06:55.075: WARN/System.err(4952):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:533)
12-17 15:06:55.075: WARN/System.err(4952):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1055)
12-17 15:06:55.075: WARN/System.err(4952):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
12-17 15:06:55.075: WARN/System.err(4952):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:88)
12-17 15:06:55.075: WARN/System.err(4952):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:927)
12-17 15:06:55.085: WARN/System.err(4952):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:909)
12-17 15:06:55.085: WARN/System.err(4952):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1152)
12-17 15:06:55.085: WARN/System.err(4952):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:653)
```

How to solve this problem

Comment: what's the url? Are you sure your server is up?

Comment: is the server reachable and does it accept connections?

Comment: yes my server is up and this error comes some times only

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is happening because some times your server is taking too long to respond. Actually this could also happening due to a slow network, so you don't have full control over it. If you were using [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html), you could increase the timeout period:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, WAIT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);

client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
```

`CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` is the time to wait for a connection to establish. `WAIT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT` is the time to wait for data to be received - in your case this is what you need to increase.

Bottom line:

- Stop using URL and start using HttpClient now.
- The situation you are describing is a very common one in a production application and you need to cater for it. Increasing the timeout won't always help, as your application will appear to halt when there is a slow network. You could add a retry mechanism or inform the user that the request has failed and ask him to try again.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I had the case that you are passing a wrong url, and the app is looking to retrieve the data, but never finds it. Check your url, maybe if you correct it, just in case that it would be wrong, then the request would not throws you that error.