# KSOAP2 OutOfMemory passing large data

Tags: android, ksoap2

http://pastebin.com/ntp3hi7j

With the code above I can download few data, like 'Limit = 5/10', but when I'm trying to download the 'Limit = 50', it gives me the following error:

```
> 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598): FATAL EXCEPTION:
> pool-1-thread-1 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 10-02 06:44:28.075:
> E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
> 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
> 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:271) 10-02
> 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):    at
> org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1338) 10-02
> 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):    at
> org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:390) 10-02 06:44:28.075:
> E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310) 10-02 06:44:28.075:
> E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextText(KXmlParser.java:2056) 10-02
> 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):    at
> org.ksoap2.serialization.DM.readInstance(DM.java:35) 10-02
> 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):    at
> org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readInstance(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:428)
> 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:387)
> 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:273)
> 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:389)
> 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:151)
> 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140) 10-02
> 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):    at
> org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:118) 10-02
> 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):    at
> org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:253)
> 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
> 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:111)
> 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> com.example.inforlider.SyncActivity$4.run(SyncActivity.java:189) 10-02
> 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
> 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
> 10-02 06:44:28.075: E/AndroidRuntime(27598):  at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Probably one of the problems could be because of the field "Image" since it's a BLOB and returns a very large String?

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Try to make pagination in web services response , its handy way to download huge data  on  demand base

Answer (score 0):

Get and save your soap xml to phone storage, then parse it. You shouldn't parse it when xml stored on  memory.

you can refer this: [How to download XML file from server and save it in SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986376/how-to-download-xml-file-from-server-and-save-it-in-sd-card)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by not include the field "Image", since it's a BLOB (big data) in the function. Before, I created another function only to read the field "Image".