# How to fetch xml from web services and save it in assets

Tags: android, xml, database, web-services

I am developing an android app and in that I want to use a XML file. I think its a kinda web services and i want to use it in my app. so first of all i am thinking that whenever I open my app it fetch the whole XML file from http://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Date-Wise-Prices-all-Commodity.xml and save it into assets folder of my App and then after I will use this XML from my assets folder.

I know this stuff is not too much difficult but actually i am new to android that's why getting this type of problem.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can directly parse the .xml file from web and then set values in your application.So for this you have to write xml parser for this.

Comment: Please check this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The assets folder is read-only at runtime.

Pick a different location to save your data, see [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for more information.

Comment: So, please tell me what could I do for this work ? or where should I save this XML so further i can use it in my app

Comment: You can save it in sdcard. See example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986376/how-to-download-xml-file-from-server-and-save-it-in-sd-card

Comment: And then after can I use this XML for my App. Actually this XML contain some data that I want to use in my app.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in other answer you have to choose different location.
Rest method is as following.

- Make a method or class to make http request.
- Get response from given request.
- Make a xml parser (DOM Parser,Pull Parser or SAX)

these are the basic steps. hope it will help.

[Check this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: Can I have an simple example of these basic steps please ?

Comment: is is necessary to store xml? you can parse direct from http response

Comment: I am trying to store this becoz if sometime the user don't have Internet on their phone then they don't get any error. The data from the Local XML that is fetched previously can be shown to user. This is what I want.

Comment: ok then first download xml from server save it to sdcard. Then you can parse.

Comment: The example you have given is it for the same or for the direct usage ?

Comment: read this tutorial it will help you to download xml on sdcard. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

Comment: you have you read and make all required component at your own. No body can give the complete code as per you requirement.

Comment: Let me check and please stay in touch so that I can take help from you on this topic.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39402/discussion-between-deepsan-and-shiv)